# Monitor download progress with apache http components

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I have some big files to download with Apache's [Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/) and I want to be able to display some progress info to users in the admin console of my web app. What is the right way to monitor a download in progress using this library? I will create a singleton to manage the ongoing downloads, what I need is a way to inspect the open connections and find out where they are at any given time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Obtain the `Content-Length` response header first
2. Get the result as stream and process it byte-by-byte (in batches)
3. Count the bytes processed and show the user the percentage of processed bytes from the total number of bytes (obtained on the 1st step)

Comment: I was hoping for something more magical.. but this works just fine and really didn't require as much code as I thought it might.. pretty simple really.

Comment: Wow this is way simpler than the crazy async http client i was looking at doing.

Comment: Although byte by byte would be very slow.

Comment: It will be usefull to show some code. As Linus said.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Bozho's answer, here is example code how to download a file, calculate download progress as a percentage, and update a JProgressBar

```
// Download update
    public static void update(final int totalBytes, final JProgressBar progressBar) {
        // Download file using buffer
        try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(API_DOMAIN + "download").openStream());
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Files.dataDir + File.separator + "client.jar")) {

            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int totalBytesRead = 0, bytesRead;
            int progress = 0;

            // Process buffer
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Calculate progress
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                progress = (int) Math.floor(((double) totalBytesRead / totalBytes) * 100D);
                log.info(progress + "%");

                // Update UI
                int finalProgress = progress;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    progressBar.setValue(finalProgress);
                    progressBar.setString(finalProgress + "%");
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
            log.error("@Services~ Failed to update client due to: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```